# How to check if AspNetUser satisfies condition before PasswordSignInAsync?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I've added a new column to AspNetUsers using the way proposed by Microsoft:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool AdminConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

Which means that admin have to confirm user account after registering.

The default way to log in is to do that:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
     _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
     return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

But as I see I don't have any possibility to edit the code behind "PasswordSignInAsync". **So how can I add another condition that will cause this method to return result.IsNotAllowed if user's account is not confirmed by admin?**

I also don't really know how can I get some data about user from database. My DbContext where I store authorization data look like this:

```
public class AuthorizationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

And normally I would use:

```
public DbSet<SomeModel> SomeData { get; set; }
```

to access some data. But in case of AspNetUsers table that was generated for me by VisualStudio, I don't have any "c# class model" to put into DbSet. **How can I then access user data to tell if his account is for example confirmed by admin?**

Comment: Is this for asp.net-core and asp.net-identity-3?

Comment: yes, it is for asp.net-core

Comment: The data will be available under the users properties in the database.

Answer (score 7):

You can override `CanSignInAsync(TUser user)` method of `SignInManager`

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager: SignInManager<User>
{
   public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager<User> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<SignInManager<User>> logger)
            : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger){}

   public override Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(User user)
   {
       if (!user.AdminConfirmed)
           return false;

       return base.CanSignInAsync(user);
   }           
}
```

Also you need to add the `ApplicationSignInManager` as services to the services container to make it available within your application via dependency injection.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       ...    
       services.AddIdentity...
       services.AddScoped<ApplicationSignInManager>();    
}
```

Comment: Where should I place this code? What is TUser variable and from where comes from? Is this a method that PasswordSignInAsync call to check if user can log in?

Comment: In a custom SignInManager class that inherits from SignInManager<TUser>

Comment: I dont know what version this is but that method doesnt exit in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0`